# Can't transfer all my pixel data through UDP (WiFi)

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, esp32

I'm trying to send continuously and randomly generated pixel colors (80x60) in Adafruit ESP32 Feather to my C# program, over Wifi, using UDP and TCP protocols. Any other type of data I can send without problems through any of the protocols, but this String that I create that sends the 4800 (80x60) values causes some difficulty, particularly in UDP.

In the TCP protocol, all data is sent by ESP32 and received by the C# program, despite the protocol being very slow and, consequently, the video obtained by them has very few frames per second.
In the case of UDP, which was expected to be faster (and it was my great hope), the generated data is not entirely received by the C# program, and the video only has the first pixels (approximately 410 - [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH9WB.png))

Both protocols are defined the same way in the C# program, with the exception that TCP is in Stream format and UDP is in Datagrams (it is not possible to define Stream):

```
public void initiate_connection(string esp32_ip, string esp32_port, int protocoltype)
    {
        string msg;
        int port;


        if (protocoltype == 1)
        {
            protype = ProtocolType.Udp;
             socktype = SocketType.Dgram;   
        }
        else if (protocoltype == 2)
        {
            protype = ProtocolType.Tcp;           
            socktype = SocketType.Stream;
        }
        try
        {
            s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, socktype, protype);
            msg = esp32_ip;
            IPAddress adafruit_remote_IP = IPAddress.Parse(msg);
            port = int.Parse(esp32_port);
            IPEndPoint IP_Endpoint_remote = new IPEndPoint(adafruit_remote_IP, port);
             s.Connect(IP_Endpoint_remote);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }

    private string send_command_adafruit(string msg)
    {

        byte[] sent_data;
        byte[] received_data = new byte[10000];               //256

        int number_of_received_bytes;


        try
        {
            if (s.Connected)
             {
                 sent_data = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                 s.Send(sent_data);
                 number_of_received_bytes = s.Receive(received_data);
                 msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received_data, 0, number_of_received_bytes);
                 //  s.Close();
                 return msg;
             } 
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application Message: Socket NOT connect, verify your cables and conections.");
                return "-1";
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            return "-1";
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            return "-1";
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            return "-1";
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            return "-1";
        }
    }
```

On the other hand, my code in ESP32 is as follows:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <Udp.h>


const char* ssid = "SensorIR_test";
const char* password = "123456789"; 

WiFiServer server(80);

WiFiUDP Udp;
const int udpPort = 80;      // local port to listen on
int reply;      // a int to send back
String str_reply, inputs;
String str_reply_UDP[60];
int speedx;

String parameter[6];
int i, j;
int subS_l;
int index_of_S;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(250000);


delay(10);

Serial.print("Setting AP (Access Point)…");
WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
Serial.println(IP);

server.begin();
Udp.begin(udpPort);

}

void loop() {
WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients
int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();   
inputs = "";
i=1;
j=1;

if (client) {    
 
 // If a new client connects,
Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
  if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,



   client.setNoDelay(1);

 //break;

 int c=client.read();
   
   //   else {
 // teste=teste+1;

  for (int y=0; y<60; y++) {
     for (int k=0; k<80; k++) {
     //speedx=random(0,255);
     str_reply+=random(0,255);
     str_reply+=" ";
      }
   client.print(str_reply);
   Serial.print(str_reply);
   client.print(" ");       
   Serial.print(" ");
   }
   
    //  delay(1000);
   }
   }
    // Close the connection
   client.stop();
   Serial.println("TCP communication disconnected.");
   Serial.println("");
   }
   else if (packetSize) {
   //  teste=teste+1;
   for (int y=1; y<61; y++) {
   str_reply_UDP[y]="";
   }


   int d = Udp.read();
   // Serial.println(d);
   if (d==59) {    //ASCII=";"
   Serial.println("New UDP Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
   }

   else if (d==33)  {   //ASCII="!"

  for (int y=0; y<60; y++) {
     for (int k=0; k<80; k++) {
     str_reply_UDP[y]+=random(0,255);
     str_reply_UDP[y]+=" ";
  }
  }
  
  

//  str_reply+=" ";
  
   }

 //  Serial.println(str_reply);
 

Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());

for (int u=0; u<61; u++) {
  Serial.println(str_reply_UDP[u]);
  Udp.println(str_reply_UDP[u]);
}
//////Udp.println(str_reply);

Udp.endPacket();  
} 

}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an MTU problem. Assuming a single colour pixel is 3 B those 410 pixels adds up to 410x3=1230 B which approaches the maximum size of a single network frame which is a bit less than 1500B. Although the underlying IP protocol itself supports fragmentation of UDP packets (i.e. slicing one packet up to MTU-sized chunks), the simplified network stack in ESP32 likely doesn't support it. And even if it did, you wouldn't want to fragment your UDP packets for reliability and performance reasons anyway.

So, always send less than 1400 B at a time. For starters. Then on top of that you need to take care of the usual stuff that comes with unreliable transport - as romkey mentioned. Generally UDP is the correct choice for real-time critical payloads like video (because you need fine-grained control of timing which is near impossible with reliable transport), but it takes *a lot* of effort to make it work well.

Comment: "Although the UDP protocol itself supports fragmentation of packets" - strictly speaking, UDP does not perform fragmentation of user sends.  All UDP does is add a UDP header to the user's send and hand it off to IP.  It is within IP where fragmentation (and at the receiver, reassembly) happens.

Comment: Right, it's been a while since I got my hands dirty so I'm starting to forget the details. Updating...

Comment: Ok, I think I understood it! So, what I need to do is to try to divide the sending message in 4 or 5 different messages? Or should I send a smaller image and, subsequently, a smaller message?

Comment: To be honest, it's your decision. Images which fit inside an MTU (roughly 1460B) would solve a lot of problems for you :) On the other hand, if you *need to* send larger images via UDP then you need to chop the image into as many fragments as needed and send those. You'd then need to add a simple framing protocol to indicate which fragment this is, and how many there are per this image.

Answer (score -1):

UDP - the [User Datagram Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) - is called "unreliable" because it makes no guarantees about delivery. It transmits each packet a single time and does not confirm delivery or attempt retransmission if the packet isn't received. Data you transmit using it may or may not get to the destination, without any indication of problems.

UDP is generally used for low overhead protocols like DNS where a request fits in a single packet and it's enough to simply retransmit a request, and for high performance protocols like NFS where the protocol tracks what has and hasn't been received and handles retransmissions itself.

There are many reasons a receiver might not see what you transmitted, especially over Wifi where data can easily be corrupted or lost simply due to radio noise.

If you want to use UDP for reliable communications, you'll need to build your own mechanism to retransmit data that's not received. That gets complicated quickly. Unless you really know what you're doing here, you're best off simply sticking with TCP, which reliably transmits data.

Comment: "Data you transmit using it may or may not get to the destination, without any indication of problems.". Yeah, it makes sense, but wouldn't it be something random? For example, in my first try, the received image would be like 80% of the entire image, but in the second try would be like 30%. In other words, if that's the problem, would I received everytime the same amount of pixels?

Comment: Not necessarily. If packets are being dropped due to network congestion, wifi interference or issues like that then yes it would look random. If packets are being dropped because you're exhausting resources on the sender or receiver and your program is sending data in a consistent way then you'd likely see a pattern to the missing data. For instance, if your program transmitted so much data quickly that either the ESP or receiver (less likely that the receiver would unless it's another ESP) ran out of space for it, it's likely that each time you tried you'd see similar results.

Comment: I think @Tarmo's point about the MTU is likely to be the cause of your problem, but if you're breaking up the data into multiple transmits, you still can't expect UDP to deliver them reliably.

Comment: you can expect it to "normally" work though.  UDP is designed for broadcasting video.